# How to specify a timestamp in SELECT INTO in InfluxDB?

Tags: timestamp, aggregate, influxdb

In InfluxDB, I have a series `foo` and want to create a series `bar` which contains daily sums of `foo` values, from beginning of time until that day. I'd like to use `SELECT INTO` query to achieve that, but I do not know how to set the timestamps of resulting measurements.

For example, with `foo` series:

`2016-01-01T00:00:00Z   10
2016-01-02T00:00:00Z    5
2016-01-03T00:00:00Z   12
2016-01-04T00:00:00Z    1`

I'd like to compute `bar` series with cumulative sums:

`2016-01-01T00:00:00Z   10
2016-01-02T00:00:00Z   15
2016-01-03T00:00:00Z   27
2016-01-04T00:00:00Z   28`

This is suprisingly hard to achieve. A continuous query operates on a time window, and I want to *always* start the sum from first measurement.

Comment: When I'm trying `SELECT INTO` query (for each day) I can compute the sums, but I cannot specify the timestamp for them.

Comment: What you you mean? What happens to the timestamps?

Comment: can you give an example query and result? looks like downsampling is what you need https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/query_language/data_exploration/#the-into-clause but not sure what you mean by specifying timestamps.